# $\Bbb Q(a, \sqrt{\vartriangle(f)})$ is a splitting field in this case.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f\in \Bbb Q [x]$ be monic irreducible and of degree 3. Prove that if $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ is any zero of $f$ then the field $\Bbb Q(\alpha, \sqrt{\vartriangle(f)}) \subset \Bbb C$ , is a splitting field of $f$. It's neccesary that $f$ is irreducible?

Well I can start to do this problem in a very computationally way (without success) . 
Let's call the roots of $f$ by $ a,b,c$. We want to show that $b,c \in K=\Bbb Q(a,\sqrt{\vartriangle(f)}) $

Where $ \sqrt{\vartriangle(f)}=(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)=u$

Well since $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) = x^3 - x^2(a+b+c)+x(ab+ac+bc)-abc \in \Bbb Q[x]$ 
We can conclude in particular that $abc \in \Bbb Q \subset K$ but since $a \in K$ then $ bc \in K$ . And also $a+b+c  ,  a  \in K$ implies that $b+c \in K$. Until now I never used that I have $u\in K$.
Well I'll start to expand $ u= a^2b-a^2c + b^2c-b^2a+c^2a-c^2b \in K$. 
Well now maybe with some tricks I can deduce that $b,c \in K$ But i can't see it.

Please someone helpme with this computationally proof of this. And if someone has an argument using ideas of splitting fields and Galois theory are also welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is irreducible of degree $3$ we get that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=3$ and that its Galois group is either cyclic of order $3$, i.e. $C_3 (=A_3)$, or the full symmetric group $S_3$ (because these are all the transitive subgroups of $S_3$).

In the first case, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is already the splitting field of $f$. Since the discriminant is a square iff the Galois group consists of even permutations, we also get that  $\sqrt{\Delta}\in \mathbb{Q}$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{\Delta})$.

In the second case, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{\Delta}):\mathbb{Q}]=6=|S_3|$,  since $2=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta}):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $3=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ are coprime. Thus $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{\Delta})$ is a subfield of the splitting field, and of the same degree, hence equals the splitting field.